# Select data which contains value in 1 of 4 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to select rows which contain the value of the variable '$filter_objekt' in the SQL column 'objekt1' **OR** 'objekt2' **OR** 'objekt3' **OR** 'objekt4'.

This is my current query:

```
$filter_objekt = "Lorem";

$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM aktionen WHERE 
            jahr LIKE '$filter_jahr' AND 
            kunde LIKE '$filter_kunde' AND 
            kampagne LIKE '$filter_kampagne' AND 
            objekt1 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
            objekt2 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
            objekt3 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
            objekt4 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
            mediamix LIKE '$filter_mediamix' AND 
            kosten LIKE '$filter_kosten' AND 
            schulnote LIKE '$filter_schulnote' AND 
            feedback_status LIKE '$filter_feedback' 
            ORDER BY kunde ASC, aktionsname ASC");
```

At this moment the script returns every row of the table, no matter if it contains the value of '$filter_objekt' or not.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use parentheses to separate the `AND` and `OR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add the set of 4 OR's into a block with parentheses

```
SELECT * FROM aktionen WHERE 
        jahr LIKE '$filter_jahr' AND 
        kunde LIKE '$filter_kunde' AND 
        kampagne LIKE '$filter_kampagne' AND 
        (objekt1 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
        objekt2 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
        objekt3 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
        objekt4 LIKE '$filter_objekt') AND 
        mediamix LIKE '$filter_mediamix' AND 
        kosten LIKE '$filter_kosten' AND 
        schulnote LIKE '$filter_schulnote' AND 
        feedback_status LIKE '$filter_feedback' 
        ORDER BY kunde ASC, aktionsname ASC
```

Note that I changed the OR after objekt4 to AND.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need parenthesis

```
// Your code is similar to this:
WHERE A=$a AND B1=$x OR B2=$x OR B3=$x

// Which actually does this:
WHERE (A=$a AND B1=$x) OR (B2=$x) OR (B3=$x)

// And you want:
WHERE A=$a AND (B1=$x OR B2=$x OR B3=$x)
```

So in your code all you have to do is add parenthesis around your `objekt`'s

Answer (score 1):

`OR` has lower precedence than `AND`, so you need parenthesis to apply all the `AND` conditions and one of the `OR` conditions:

```
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM aktionen WHERE 
            jahr LIKE '$filter_jahr' AND 
            kunde LIKE '$filter_kunde' AND 
            kampagne LIKE '$filter_kampagne' AND 
           (objekt1 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
            objekt2 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
            objekt3 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
            objekt4 LIKE '$filter_objekt') AND /* I think you mean AND here, not OR, but I'm not 100% sure */ 
            mediamix LIKE '$filter_mediamix' AND 
            kosten LIKE '$filter_kosten' AND 
            schulnote LIKE '$filter_schulnote' AND 
            feedback_status LIKE '$filter_feedback' 
            ORDER BY kunde ASC, aktionsname ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM aktionen WHERE 
        jahr LIKE '$filter_jahr' AND 
        kunde LIKE '$filter_kunde' AND 
        kampagne LIKE '$filter_kampagne' AND 
        (
        objekt1 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
        objekt2 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
        objekt3 LIKE '$filter_objekt' OR 
        objekt4 LIKE '$filter_objekt' )AND 
        mediamix LIKE '$filter_mediamix' AND 
        kosten LIKE '$filter_kosten' AND 
        schulnote LIKE '$filter_schulnote' AND 
        feedback_status LIKE '$filter_feedback' 
        ORDER BY kunde ASC, aktionsname ASC");
```